# Ongoing competitions on reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Are there any ongoing competitions except the following?

[Battlesnake](https://play.battlesnake.com/), [SC2 AI Arena](https://aiarena.net/),
[Bomberland](https://www.gocoder.one/bomberland), [ConnectX](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/connectx/leaderboard)

Comment: It would be cool if there was somewhere that aggregated these kind of competitions. The question is not great for the AI Stack Exchange site though, because it will quickly go out of date as competitions change. It's not really possible to make an answer which is valid for more than a few months. I think it could be made better, by specifying the year. The question would then naturally go from being "current" to being a historical record.

Comment: There is still the issue that this is basically a request for a list of external resources. My suggestion would be to not exclude the ones you have found so far (but do list them in the question, to show you have done some research), make the question "Where can I find public reinforcement learning competitions for 2022?" or similar, and we can have a Community Wiki answer to try and build the list.